# Divergence of $\phi$ from p

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

I am reading a paper which is based mostly on divergence. 
I tried to get a basic understanding of divergence but I cannot see how it is linked with this aspect. 
It says: $D(\phi,p) = \phi . \log_2\phi/p + (1-\phi)\log_2((1-\phi)/(1-p))$ is called the divergence of $\phi$ from p.
I'm totally confused with this statement. Can everyone describe it in simple words to me?

EDIT: Here is the [link](http://eprints.gla.ac.uk/3798/1/3798.pdf) to the paper. The statement is on top of the 10th page just before equation (8).

Comment: Can you link to the paper to provide context?

Comment: @UmbertoP. just added the link.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence). It is a measure of the difference of probability distributions. It is unrelated to the divergence of a vector field.

Comment: I read this wikipedia page. But I still cannot find the relation between that formula to KL Divergence. Could you please demonstrate it?